# How to Create a DataFrame with Nested Array

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, dataframe

Actually i receive a Pandas generated JSON, witch i load to create a Dataframe. Its Dataframe have some nested Array columns witch i need to iterate over;

Simply loading a `pandas.read_json()` gives an column with arrays, and i cant work under that. Bellow code:

```
import pandas

dataframe = pandas.read_json('/Users/***/Downloads/df_teste.json', orient='table')
print(dataframe)
```

Returns me an Dataframe like the above:

| student_id | name | created_at | languages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 2019-01-03 14:30:32.146000+00:00 | [{'language_id': 1, 'name': 'English', 'optin_... |
| 2 | Bar | 2019-01-03 14:30:32.146000+00:00 | [{'language_id': 1, 'name': 'English', 'optin_... |

And my question is: How can i read like this one?

| student_id | language_id | language_name | optin_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | English | 2019-01-03T14:30:32.148Z |
| 2 | 1 | English | 2021-05-30T00:33:02.915Z |
| 2 | 2 | Portuguese | 2022-03-07T07:42:07.082Z |

For testing purposes, i am loading using the bellow JSON:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      { "name": "student_id", "type": "string" },
      { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
      { "name": "created_at", "type": "datetime", "tz": "UTC" },
      { "name": "languages", "type": "string" }
    ],
    "pandas_version": "0.20.0"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "name": "Foo",
      "created_at": "2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z",
      "languages": [
        {
          "language_id": 1,
          "name": "English",
          "optin_at": "2019-01-03T14:30:32.148Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "student_id": "2",
      "name": "Bar",
      "created_at": "2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z",
      "languages": [
        {
          "language_id": 1,
          "name": "English",
          "optin_at": "2021-05-30T00:33:02.915Z"
        },
        {
          "language_id": 2,
          "name": "Portuguese",
          "optin_at": "2022-03-07T07:42:07.082Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json_normalize to make expected output, Here I have created the expected output with use of json_normalize from your input json.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

data = {
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      { "name": "student_id", "type": "string" },
      { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
      { "name": "created_at", "type": "datetime", "tz": "UTC" },
      { "name": "languages", "type": "string" }
    ],
    "pandas_version": "0.20.0"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "name": "Foo",
      "created_at": "2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z",
      "languages": [
        {
          "language_id": 1,
          "name": "English",
          "optin_at": "2019-01-03T14:30:32.148Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "student_id": "2",
      "name": "Bar",
      "created_at": "2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z",
      "languages": [
        {
          "language_id": 1,
          "name": "English",
          "optin_at": "2021-05-30T00:33:02.915Z"
        },
        {
          "language_id": 2,
          "name": "Portuguese",
          "optin_at": "2022-03-07T07:42:07.082Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


student_detail = ['student_id']
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'], 'languages', student_detail)
print(df)
```

By printing the df you can get the output you want.
Here is the output. Ps the columns are unordered you can order it. Thanks

```
language_id        name                  optin_at student_id
0            1     English  2019-01-03T14:30:32.148Z          1
1            1     English  2021-05-30T00:33:02.915Z          2
2            2  Portuguese  2022-03-07T07:42:07.082Z          2
```

Hope it helps, If not please do let know. Thanks,

PS: Im  not sure this is what something you expecting. You can simply use pd.to_datetime on the optin_at column. I have provided code below,

```
df['optin_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['optin_at'])
print(df['optin_at'])
```

If you add this two lines, it prints the optin_at in datetime format.
Output

```
0   2019-01-03 14:30:32.148000+00:00
1   2021-05-30 00:33:02.915000+00:00
2   2022-03-07 07:42:07.082000+00:00
```

Hope this helps, let know if this is not case. Thanks

Comment: How can i read the `optin_at` column like an datetime object?